# javascript - get index in Map.prototype.forEach()

Tags: javascript, dictionary, ecmascript-6

`Map.prototype.forEach` takes callback with two params: value and key.
Is it possible to get the index of each entry, similar to `Array.prototype.forEach((value, index) => {})`

Comment: Quick answer for future visitors: No- the callback's signature only includes `value, key, map`. Instead, declare a counter variable before the forEach an increment within the loop.
`let index = 0
myMap.forEach((value) => {
/* do something */
index++;
});
`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> `Map.prototype.forEach` takes callback with two params: value and key.

No, it's [invoked with *three* arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach), just like `Array#forEach`. The third is the map.

> Is it possible to get the index of each entry, similar to `Array.prototype.forEach(functcion(value, index) => {})`

*(Fairly sure the `functcion` part of that wasn't meant to be there.)*

That's what `key` is. There is no separate "index."

`Map`'s iteration order is defined for various iteration operations, but there's no *direct* iteration construct that gives you the *index* (as opposed to *key*) of an entry in that order. The order is *original key insertion order*, so for instance:

```
const m = new Map();
m.set("x", 1);
m.set("q", 2);
m.set("z"), 3);
m.set("x", "one");
```

If we loop through that map, we'll see the keys in the order the key was **first** added, so `"x"`, `"q"`, `"z"`. Note that changing the value of the entry with the ke `"x"` **didn't** move it to the end.

[`Map#forEach`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-map.prototype.foreach) (and `for-of` and anything else using the map's iterator) follows the iteration order, so if you're thinking of the index in terms of that order, you could track the index yourself:

```js
const m = new Map();
m.set("one", "uno");
m.set("two", "due");
m.set("three", "tre");
let index = 0;
m.forEach((value, key) => {
  console.log(index++, key, value);
});
```

Alternately, you can get an array of the map entries (as `[key, value]` arrays):

```
let entries = Array.from(m.entries());
```

...and use the indexes of that array:

I'm just not sure what it buys you. :-)

Comment: If you don't like side-effects, like `index` variable, you can use map.keys() and get index from there `m.forEach((value, key) => console.log(Array.from(m.keys()).indexOf(key)))`

Comment: @just-boris: No, the only order guarantee I can find in the specification is **only** in relation to `Map#forEach`, not iteration order generally, so in theory `keys` and `entries` could be in a different order. (I find this odd, that the order would be specified for one operation only [rather than all or none], but I looked pretty carefully.) Unless you can point to something in the spec (as opposed to MDN) that I missed (he said hopefully)?

Comment: You are right, I just showed how to get a number from key without extra counter. Order doesn't matter, but every key will get a unique number, right?

Comment: @just-boris: But not necessarily a reliable one; per spec, the keys could be returned in any order at all by `keys`. The closest thing to order Maps have is the original-key-insertion-order guarantee on `forEach`. (Which is a good reason not to rely on the order, but... :-) )

Comment: @DotBot - Since the `functcion` appears in the question and I'm quoting it, removing it isn't appropriate.

Comment: My bad @T.J.Crowder, us programmers and our OCD eyes ;)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. Map object is a key/value map. To me at least the idea of an index doesn't make much sense, given that the order of the key/value pairs should not be guaranteed in a Map. If you are just curious how many pairs you have iterated on so far, you could just keep a counter that you mutate on each call, something like:

```
mapObj.forEach(() => {
    let i=0;
    return (key, value) => {
        // whatever you are doing with each key/value
        i += 1;
    }
});
```

It is not as elegant as an index as parameter, but would at least meet your needs.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is defining what an index is. The spec defines a [[MapNextIndex]] internal slot of iterators, which stores the index of the [[MapData]] list which contains the next entry.

However, there is no way to access these indices. Even more, implementations are not required to internally behave like described by the spec, so they may not have these indices at all.

> The data structures used in this Map objects specification is only
>   intended to describe the required observable semantics of Map objects.
>   It is not intended to be a viable implementation model.

What you can do is use an index which says how many times you have to call `next()` on a new iterator in order to get that entry. These kind of indexes are not absolute, and may become obsolete if you alter the map. Just initialize a counter to `0`, and increase it at each iteration.

```
{
  let i = 0;
  for(var [key,value] of map) {
    // Do something
    ++i;
  }
}
```